# Easy way to save and restore Virtual Network Editor settings in VMware Workstation

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, vmware-workstation

I am using VMware Workstation 10 and have set up my Virtual Network Editor to use multiple NICs. Due to some reason (automatic updates I guess) the VNE loses those settings every now and then. Is there any *easy* way to save and restore those settings? In the VMware communities I have found a solution which copies registry entries, but that would require me to search all the appropriate keys by hand and write a unique script for every computer that runs Workstation (up to now five in total).
Here is the link: https://communities.vmware.com/message/157381

So I was wondering if there could be an easier way, for example by using vmrun.exe in the CLI. Just something which does not require writing a new script for each machine.

Comment: I have found a solution for Linux hosts which would be exactly what I am looking for:
http://serverfault.com/questions/535193/vmware-workstation-how-to-automate-or-script-changes-to-the-virtual-network-co
But I can't find the equivalent of /etc/vmware/networking in Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question was answered by the folks of the VMware communities.

To export the settings, one can use
    "C:\Program Files (x86)\VMware\VMware Workstation\vnetlib.exe" -- export D:\VNE-Backup.txt
On 64bit hosts replace vnetlib.exe with vnetlib64.exe. The command has to be run from an elevated command prompt.
To import the settings simply replace "export" with "import".